# How to write a script in R that will run a function multiple times but save to different variables

Tags: r, function, variables, multiple-results

I was given a function that runs analyses on datasets  so I'll try my best to explain my problem.

Say I have a function: `functionx()`

This function will run an analysis on a data matrix: `matrixd`. However, I need to run `functionx()` 50 times on `matrixd`, but I need to save the results from each time I run the function to a different variable, say `results1`, `results2`,..., `results50`.

How would I write a script that would accomplish this?

Comment: I'm guessing `replicate(50, functionx(x))` would be fine. That creates a list which is going to be way easier to use than a bunch of differently named variables in the long run. you could always convert it with `list2env` if you really need to (and you really don;t). For anything more specific, you really do need to do the work to create a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Talking about code abstractly like this isn't useful or helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your link was very relevant to my problem, and I'll try my best to make my coding questions more specific in the future.